# preg_match para pegar palavras entre aspas simples e retirar espaços em branco do final de match[1] com a mesma pattern é possível?

Tags: php, preg-match

Conforme as strings abaixo, usando preg_match, preciso de uma pattern que seja capaz de separar o que está dentro e fora das aspas simples além de retirar do $match[1] espaços em branco do final da string. É possível?

```
<?php

$string_1 = "Scorpions 'Scorpions Dynamite'";
$string_2 = "Scorpions 'Scorpions 'Dynamite''";

$pattern = "/(.*)'([^\']+)'/";

$s1 = preg_match ($patern, $string_1, $match);

$s2 = preg_match ($patern, $string_2, $match);

print_r ($s1);

print_r ($s2);
?>
```

Resultado do código acima:

```
s1 = array (
  0 => 'Scorpions \'Scorpions Dynamite\'',
  1 => 'Scorpions ',
  2 => 'Scorpions Dynamite',
)

s2 = array (
  0 => 'Scorpions \'Scorpions \'Dynamite\'',
  1 => 'Scorpions \'Scorpions ',
  2 => 'Dynamite',
)
```

Com muita dificuldade cheguei nesta pattern aqui, mas não é o bastante... Agradeço pela ajuda.

```
$pattern = "/(.*)'([^\']+)'/";
```

ADENDO :

O que preciso é modificar a pattern de tal foma que do array $match[1] apareça somente palavras símples, sem espaços em branco o final [somente caracteres alfanuméricos], porque como podem ver, até uma aspas escapou para o match e reapareceu em um dos índices do array e isto dá erro numa aplicação json que tenho aqui.

Deveria ser assim a saída nos dois arrays:

```
array (
  0 => 'Scorpions \'Scorpions Dynamite\'',
  1 => 'Scorpions',
  2 => 'Scorpions Dynamite',
)

array (
  0 => 'Scorpions \'Scorpions \'Dynamite\'',
  1 => 'Scorpions Scorpions',
  2 => 'Dynamite',
)
```

Não sei se fui claro, se quiserem explico de novo

Answer (score 2):

Só pra constar, seus códigos aqui não imprimem arrays:

```
print_r ($s1);

print_r ($s2);
```

Apesar de você afirmar que a saída é um array, e outra coisa, no nome da variável é `$pattern`, mas você perdeu um `t` em:

```
preg_match ($patern, $string_1, $match);
```

Sobre o problema da pergunta, realmente você **não precisa** fazer um [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) **monstruoso**, basta tratar espaços extras como:

```
1 => 'Scorpions ',
```

Com a função `trim` iterando em um `foreach`, é simples:

```
<?php

$string_1 = "Scorpions 'Scorpions Dynamite'";
$string_2 = "Scorpions 'Scorpions 'Dynamite''";

$pattern = "/(.*)'([^\']+)'/";

$s1 = preg_match($pattern, $string_1, $match1);
$s2 = preg_match($pattern, $string_2, $match2);

foreach ($match1 as &$value) {
    $value = trim($value);
}

foreach ($match2 as &$value) {
    $value = trim($value);
}

var_dump($match1);

var_dump($match2);
```

Usei `var_dump` pra ver com melhor detalhes a saída, veja um exemplo online do teste: https://ideone.com/fTESzq

E note que o indice `0` que é o *match todo* você pode remove-lo com a função `array_shift`, assim:

```
array_shift($match1);
array_shift($match2);
```

Que resultaria em:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Scorpions"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "Scorpions Dynamite"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "Scorpions 'Scorpions"
  [1]=>
  &string(8) "Dynamite"
}
```